# Instalar y/o desinstalar paquetes en entorno virtual Activado, también lo hace de forma global

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando Windows 10 - con Python.
Al instalar paquetes o librerías con un entorno virtual creado y activado, la instalación se realiza de forma global, no solamente en el entorno local (virtual).
De la misma forma al desinstalar paquetes con el entorno virtual activo, también se desinstalan de forma global.

Al ejecutar el comando `pip list`, o `pip freeze` para ver los paquetes instalados, el resultado obtenido desde la consola para el usuario principal, son los mismos que dentro de la ruta donde estoy haciendo el proyecto con el entorno virtual activo.

```txt
C:\Users\samid>pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
asgiref      3.7.2
distlib      0.3.6
filelock     3.9.0
pip          24.0
platformdirs 2.6.2
setuptools   65.5.0
sqlparse     0.4.4
tzdata       2024.1
virtualenv   20.17.1
```

```txt
(venv) D:\Documents-Developers\Curso Desarrollo Python - RUTA Aprendizaje - CF\03_Django-CF\Project-facilito_store>pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
asgiref      3.7.2
distlib      0.3.6
filelock     3.9.0
pip          24.0
platformdirs 2.6.2
setuptools   65.5.0
sqlparse     0.4.4
tzdata       2024.1
virtualenv   20.17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip` es independiente de la instalaciones python y necesita de una instalación aparte. Posiblemente no lo tengas instalado en tu entorno virtual y estés siempre usando `pip` desde la instalación global.

Para estos casos, la librería python tiene el módulo `ensurepip` que garantiza la instalación de `pip`.

Ejecuta lo siguiente dentro del entorno virtual:

```sh
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Asegúrate que estés usando el intérprete python de tu entorno virtual.

Lo normal es haber incluido `pip` entre las dependencias al crear el entorno virtual para no tener que instalarlo después.

Comment: Gracias, Funcionando. Ahora los paquetes instalados quedan solamente en el entorno virtual y no en el global @ChemaCortes